# HTML Loading canvas data from cookies

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, canvas

I am coming into an issue where i am trying to load my canvas data from a cookie but when i load the data the following error occurs.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'putImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': No function was found that matched the signature provided.
```

What i am trying to do is save canvas data to a cookie when a button is pressed and then when another button is pressed i want to read and then redraw this data on the canvas.

```
if (document.getElementById('hdnSwitchButton').getAttribute("Value") == 0) {
            canvas.style.zIndex = "-2";
        } else if (document.getElementById('hdnSwitchButton').getAttribute("Value") == 1) {
            canvas.style.zIndex = "0";
            canvasRead = getCookie("canvas");
            if (!canvasRead) {
                alert('Error: Cannot read canvas!');
            } else {
                context.putImageData(canvasRead, 0, 0);
            }
        }
```

this is my initiliase code where it reads the cookie and the error occurs on the line:

```
context.putImageData(canvasRead, 0, 0);
```

When saving a cookie this is my code:

```
    function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i].trim();
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
    return "";
}

function BrowserButtonClick() {
    document.getElementById('hdnSwitchButton').setAttribute('Value', 0);
    canvasSave = context.getImageData(0, 0, aWidth, aHeight);
    document.cookie = "canvas=" + canvasSave;
}
```

And my html canvas code is as follows:

```
                        <div class="canvas">
                        <canvas id = "DrawingCanvas">
                            <p>Unfortunately, your browser is currently unsupported by our web application. We are sorry for the inconvenience. Please use one of the supported browsers listed below.</p>
                            <p>Supported browsers: <a href="http://www.google.com/intl/en_uk/chrome/browser/">Chrome</a>, <a href="http://www.opera.com">Opera</a>, <a href="http://www.mozilla.com">Firefox</a>, <a href="http://www.apple.com/safari">Safari</a>, and <a href="http://www.konqueror.org">Konqueror</a>.</p>
                        </canvas>
                    </div>
```

What i would like to know is why this is happening and how i can go about loading my canvas from the cookie with no issues or better yet a more efficient way of loading canvas data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your canvas is defined by its `imageData` object.

The imageData object contains everything necessary to redraw your canvas after it has been serialized and saved.  imageData is an object, but the important part of imageData is its `data` property that holds an array representing every pixel on your canvas.

You can reload your canvas by saving and restoring this pixel array in your cookie.

*But...*

...having said that, the resulting cookie is likely to be large--megabytes large.  You might want to consider saving your canvas pixels as an image (using canvas.toDataURL) which creates a smaller image file that you can save.

Anyway, to answer your question...

A Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/c8Vnf/

**Save**

- Use `context.getImageData` to get the imageData object that defines your canvas.
- The pixel content is stored in an RGBA data array on the imageData object (imageData.data).
- Convert that array to a string with `JSON.stringify`
- Save that string as a cookie.

**Restore**

- To restore your canvas, get the cookie string and then convert that string back into an array with `JSON.parse`.
- Use `context.getImageData` to get an imageData object representing your canvas:
- Fill the pixel data array of the imageData object with the saved pixel data:
- Push the modified imageData object back onto the canvas with `context.putImageData`:

Code for saving:

```
var imgData=ctx.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

J=JSON.stringify(imgData.data);

// and save J as a cookie
```

Code for restoring:

```
var savedData=JSON.parse(J);

var imgData=ctx.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

var data=imgData.data;

for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){

    data[i]=savedData[i];

}

ctx.putImageData(imgData,0,0);
```